# How do I programmatically clear or update a phone number for Azure AD B2C MFA?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are testing MFA on Azure AD B2C using the sample found here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-unknown-devices

We know it can be done via the Azure Portal, but it is not an option for us to give customers access to our tenant (customer self service).

Previous posts pointed me to wait for an update from Graph API, and we are playing with the beta now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-beta

Running [Get authenticationMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) only shows Azure AD B2C users with MFA enabled as having password authentication, no phone number.

Anyone been able to get the beta Graph API working with Azure AD B2C MFA or come up with a workaround clearing/updating phone numbers?

Comment: Thinking this is either a bug with the beta Microsoft Graph API or it does not support Azure AD B2C MFA. Confirmed if I use the portal to enter a phone number for a user that it does return from the Graph API. Whenever it is populated from Azure AD B2C MFA enrollment, it does not return from the Graph API. Only difference I can see is that Azure AD B2C MFA populates a number with no space (+15555555555) and the portal enforces the use of a space (+1 5555555555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Graph API does not appear to be the answer, we were able to find a sample Azure AD B2C custom policy that allows a user to edit their phone number. To get a "reset" functionality, we added a check for a claim that would designate the user needs to reenroll in MFA and then trigger this workflow.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph API does not support this operation for B2C. Please go through MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations) which can give you more information about Microsoft Graph operations available for Azure AD B2C.

Comment: That link now states that the GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/authentication/phoneMethods method does work. I confirmed that I can get a list of phone methods if they are in the proper format. Unfortunately B2C saves them in an INVALID format (missing space between the country code and the area code (+15555555555 instead of +1 5555555555). Is this a known issue? I am planning on opening a ticket with Microsoft in hopes that they will fix this issue and allow valid AND "invalid" phone numbers to be returned through the API.

Comment: Hi @ScottMcNeany, please raise a new question in Stackoverflow with complete details of the scenario such that me or someone in my team will help you.

Comment: Hi @Hari Krishna - thank you for your help! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200556/bug-identified-in-azure-b2c-mfa-phone-number-format-missing-spaces