# Bug identified in Azure B2C MFA phone number format (missing spaces)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

This was suggested by Hari Krishna on another thread to open a new SO thread for this discussion. [How do I programmatically clear or update a phone number for Azure AD B2C MFA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584656/how-do-i-programmatically-clear-or-update-a-phone-number-for-azure-ad-b2c-mfa/62599032?noredirect=1#comment115256996_62599032)

We are using B2C custom policies with a step to write back the user's MFA profile to the B2C profile. The B2C technical profile name is **AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId**.

```
<!-- Save MFA phone number: The precondition verifies whether the user provided a new number in the 
             previous step. If so, then the phone number is stored in the directory for future authentication requests. -->

<OrchestrationStep Order="12" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>newPhoneNumberEntered</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

When this value is written back to B2C under Users->Authentication Methods->Phone, it does so in the format +12223334444 with no space in between the country code and the area code. B2C accepts this value and subsequent MFA requests work just fine.

**However**, the bug appears when you go to administer the MFA phone number using the Graph API methods under [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/authentication/phoneMethods](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D/authentication/phoneMethods). When calling the GET method, any phone number not in the format +1 2223334444 (note the spaces b/w country code and area code this time) is ignored and the result is an empty array.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('{userId}')/authentication/phoneMethods",
    "value": []
}
```

Furthermore, the value cannot be deleted. Calling DELETE [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/authentication/phoneMethods/3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D/authentication/phoneMethods/3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7) results in a 404 with the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "resourceNotFound",
        "message": "Unable to delete authentication method of the requested type with an id of [3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7] because it was not found for the user.",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Unable to delete authentication method of the requested type with an id of [3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7] because it was not found for the user.",
            "date": "2020-12-08T14:02:53",
            "request-id": "eba02037-1884-4dce-9faf-ceb1e377975b",
            "client-request-id": "eba02037-1884-4dce-9faf-ceb1e377975b"
        }
    }
}
```

The one thing that does work is to perform a "ghost update" with a PATCH request and then a subsequent DELETE requests that will result in a blank phone number and then the user will be re-prompted to enter their new phone number on the next B2C sign-in attempt. See below.

**Step 1 - Issue a "ghost update" to set the MFA phone number to a dummy value.**

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/authentication/phoneMethods](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D/authentication/phoneMethods)

```
{
  "phoneNumber": "+1 2223334444",
  "phoneType": "mobile"
}
```

**Step 2 - Delete the dummy phone number, which is now allowed since it's in the correct format**

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/authentication/phoneMethods/3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7
```

This ultimately allows for a semi-suitable workaround because it allows an administrator to clear the old phone number so the user is re-prompted, but it is definitely a bug and prevents the administrator from viewing the existing phone number for verification purposes, which results in reduced security.

Comment: Azure Portal are also using Microsoft Graph to update the MFA phone number. I think **AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId** are using another API to update the phone number. In order to maintain consistency, you should verify and restrict the format of the phone number in the custom policy before saving it to AAD.

Comment: Was this phone number captured by the phonefactor technical profile?

Comment: Correct - specifically "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile

Comment: @ScottMcNeany I'm running into a very similar issue with ADB2C. I can't get the phone deleted using the "DeleteClaims" operation (AD technical profile). I noticed the same observation as you did (the space difference). I was wondering if you ended up solving the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: @bilby91 - we 'solved' the issue by moving away from the out-of-the-box B2C storage for MFA phone numbers. Instead, we store the phone numbers in a custom database and pull them in via a REST API for the user to authenticate. When they add a new one, we call another REST API to store the phone number.

Comment: @ScottMcNeany Thanks for the response! I still have a support ticket open with them and they are still trying to figure out what's going on. It's been months since we have had this case open. I suspect we are going to land on a similar solution, unfortunately.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue. Has there been any update on this issue/ticket with them? Is there a way to customize the AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId technical profile to properly put in the space between the country code and phone number?

Comment: Three years later - and this still seems to be the only workaround. I have another thread open inquiring whether there are any better options, including whether there are any policy modifications to add the space.