# AAD B2C "Call Me" option not initiating a phone call for MFA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Our application uses MFA enabled by a user flow on a B2C tenant.  We recently got reports that the "Call Me" button on the MFA challenge screen is no longer working. The user can click the button, but never gets a phone call. I can reproduce this problem on my test user account with a known good phone number.  I can click the button to send a text and that comes through, but the phone call does not.  The audit logs indicate that the phone number is invalid.  I'm waiting to hear back from MS support, but wanted to post here in case anyone else was having trouble.  I wonder if it could be related to this: [Bug identified in Azure B2C MFA phone number format (missing spaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200556/bug-identified-in-azure-b2c-mfa-phone-number-format-missing-spaces)

Comment: Thanks @atobrandon. Please follow this document and it will help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication

Comment: Hi @Jit_MSFT, I reviewed the link, but that's not what I'm asking about.  We don't use or want One Time Passwords.  We are using MFA enabled by a Sign-In User Flow as documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows.  It has been working fine for years and then users reported it stopped working a couple of weeks ago. We haven't made any changes that should or could have caused the MFA phone call to stop working as it is completely handled by AAD B2C.