# How to get MFA kind of id? (Azure B2C Custom Policy MFA)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm struggled with b2c custom policy.
Does anyone know how to get MFA id via custom policy?

My app registers MFA phone-number via custom policy. After a user sign up. We would like to allow user to update their MFA phone number via our app.
So I think MS-Graph is one option.(I know following article is beta-version.)
But following article says that I need kind of "id" according to MFA phone-number.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/phoneauthenticationmethod?view=graph-rest-beta

My questions are

1. how to get id from via custom policy?
2. Any other way to update MFA phone number via MS-graph?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to check my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD B2C custom policy and Microsoft Graph belong to completely different systems.

The `id` mentioned in MS Graph document can only be available in Microsoft Graph. There is no direct way to get it in Custom policy.

You need to call Microsoft Graph [List phoneMethods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-phonemethods?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) somehow in Custom policy to get the MFA id by following [Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro). (similar steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875609/calling-the-azure-ad-graph-api-from-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy?answertab=votes#tab-top))

But based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584656/how-do-i-programmatically-clear-or-update-a-phone-number-for-azure-ad-b2c-mfa), it seems that if using Microsoft Graph, the format of the phone number is different with the one in Azure portal.

**So you can choose** to implement this sample [Azure AD B2C: Edit MFA phone number](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number) suggested in that answer.

Comment: Thank you Allen. Recently I couldn't access Internet...Because of  network trouble kind of thing. Your answer is really helpful  and I decided to take the way that Edit MFA phone number.